# How many pam.d modules?

Tags: 12.04, pam

Does anyone know what command(s) can I use to find out how many pam.d modules are on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straight forward way, because:

- In `/etc/pam.conf` and in the the PAM configuration files residing in the directory `/etc/pam.d/`, while declaring the relevant type/module use the below format:

  ```
  <service> type module module_args
  ```

  the `module` can be located anywhere on the system and it can be an absolute or relative path. If a relative path is used, then Ubuntu looks in `/lib/security/` and `/lib/ARCHITECTURE/security/` directories for the module, this is a OS dependent behavior though
- Even if you guess (or manage to get) the possible locations, you could not be sure about the file name because there is no strict rule for module name, generally everyone tend to use `pam_*.so` to keep it easily understandable and sort of generic.

So, at most, you can look out for all the `pam_*.so` files in the system currently, you can add any other possible manual module file that might be added, although eventually this can not give you the absolute confirmation, this could be thought of as the closest approximation.

Now, to search for all files on block device backed filesystems in the system that starts with `pam_` and ends in `.so`, do:

```
sudo updatedb && locate --regex '.*/pam_[^/]+\.so$'
```

On my system:

```
% locate --regex '.*/pam_[^/]+\.so$' 
/lib/security/pam_ecryptfs.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_access.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_cap.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_debug.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_deny.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_echo.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_env.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_exec.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_faildelay.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_filter.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_ftp.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_gnome_keyring.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_group.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_issue.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_keyinit.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_lastlog.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_limits.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_listfile.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_localuser.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_loginuid.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_mail.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_mkhomedir.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_motd.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_namespace.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_nologin.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_permit.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_pwhistory.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_rhosts.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_rootok.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_securetty.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_selinux.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_sepermit.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_shells.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_stress.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_succeed_if.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_systemd.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_tally.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_tally2.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_time.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_timestamp.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_tty_audit.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_umask.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_unix.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_userdb.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_warn.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_wheel.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_xauth.so
```